# Add a multi-column legend key Mapbox JS

Tags: java, mapbox, legend, mapbox-gl-js

How can I create a multi-column legend key that has both text and color keys?

I was able to add a single column legend with color keys using this example: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/updating-choropleth/

However, I was wondering if it’s possible to do a multi-column legend, like a table in mapbox?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legend is not part of Mapbox GL, just an HTML/CSS element that is absolutely positioned over the map.
So if you need a 2D legend you can simply replace it with a `<table>` element:

```
<table style="position: absolute; bottom: 30px; right: 10px; z-index:1, backgroung-color: white">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Row 1</th>
    <td>(1, 1) value </td>
    <td>(1, 2) value</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Row 2</th>
    <td>(2, 1) value</td>
    <td>(2, 2) value</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @MeltedPenguin I want to add color-based labels within the table itself, how do i do that? For what I have so far, see here: https://files.fm/u/bu2nhbhu . For what i want it to look like see here: https://files.fm/u/g6jvbztx.

Comment: The color-based labels are created by all the `<span style='background-color: hsl(326, 86%, 53%)'></span>` elements. So what you need to do is replace each `Row X` in my example with such a styled `<span>`